# s3fs - how to disable caching?

Tags: amazon-s3, s3fs

We'd like to use s3fs to mount an s3 bucket (or folder in a bucket) to a docker container.  Our s3fs is v1.84, our docker container os is Alpine Linux.

We are mounting an s3 bucket:/folder in our docker container with

```
s3fs $DEBUG_OPTS ${S3FS_ARGS} -o passwd_file=${AWS_S3_AUTHFILE} -o url=${AWS_S3_URL} -o uid=$OWNER -o use_cache="" dataops-datastore:/Testuser ${AWS_S3_MOUNT}
```

the error we are seeing is
s3fs: There is no enough disk space for used as cache(or temporary) directory by s3fs.
Mount failure

In the documentation the  '-o use_cache=""' option is supposed to disable local caching.  Why is the error we're seeing indicating that s3fs is still trying to cache the bucket locally?

Comment: Which operation uses temporary space, read or write?

Comment: How much disk space is available ?

Answer (score 0):

s3fs currently creates a local temporary file for writes which syncs to S3 during close or fsync.  It does this to allow random writes to different offsets in the file.

goofys, an alternative S3 file system, instead writes directly in 10 MB parts to S3.  This does not require temporary space but does not allow random writes.